# Problem in Converting an image (jpg) to Base64 format in Javascript

Tags: javascript, image-processing, base64, jpeg

I need to read an image file from the local hard drive and convert the same to base64 format. After conversion i need to pass the base64 string to a webservice and get the result from a webservice.

I have a code for the same:

```
<html>

<script>
// create the object

//test = new Base64();

x = new XMLHttpRequest();

// set the function that should be called when
// the ready state changes (the callback)
x.onreadystatechange = handleDoc;
// establish the method and URL
//x.open('GET', "Latest Eticket.jpg", true);
x.overrideMimeType("text/plain; charset=x-user-defined");
x.open('GET', 'file:///C:\\vishwa\\Node_JS\\Jquery_ajax\\JS_with_Ajax\\base64_encode\\Latest Eticket.jpg', true);
//x.open('GET', 'C:\vishwa\Node_JS\Jquery_ajax\JS_with_Ajax\base64_encode\Latest Eticket.jpg', true);
//x.open('GET', 'http://www.google.co.in/imgres?imgurl=http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_PveGYAt2T10/TDRH1kJsXAI/AAAAAAAAAgI/a45pNA5hxrA/s1600/hi-pig.jpg&imgrefurl=http://weiwei95.blogspot.com/2010_07_01_archive.html&usg=__k761BPCJk7FGxAgy8UHUiCCO1dA=&h=474&w=600&sz=51&hl=en&start=1&sig2=K2Z27chXr6EPO-lHJVY43g&zoom=1&tbnid=NSx-UedGEdm84M:&tbnh=107&tbnw=135&ei=uezUTbaDFMSBgAet_7iVDA&prev=/search%3Fq%3Dhi%26hl%3Den%26biw%3D1024%26bih%3D548%26gbv%3D2%26tbm%3Disch&itbs=1', true);
//x.open('GET', 'http://localhost:80//Latest Eticket.jpg', true);
// initiate the HTTP transaction
x.send(null);


//
function handleDoc() {
//window.alert("READY STATE IS " +
//x.readyState);
if(x.readyState == 1)
{
    window.alert("Handling x 1 State: The response is started");
}
if(x.readyState == 4)
{
    var encodeImagescanned_image = '';
    alert("Am i coming here 4-2"+x.responseText);
                    //var base64 = new Base64();
                    encodeImagescanned_image = encode(x.responseText);
                    alert("Am i coming here 4-3"+encodeImagescanned_image);
    window.alert("Handling x 4 State: The response is ended");

    alert("Constructing Soap body");
    var xmlp = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:dsf=\"http://DSFService/\">" +
                    "<soapenv:Header/>" +
                    "<soapenv:Body>" +
                    "<dsf:FieldExtraction>" +
                    "<dsf:inImage>" +
                    this.encodeImagescanned_image +
                    "</dsf:inImage>" +
                    "</dsf:FieldExtraction>" +
                    "</soapenv:Body>" +
                    "</soapenv:Envelope>";
                    var xmlps = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:dsf=\"http://DSFService/\">" +
                    "<soapenv:Header/>" +
                    "<soapenv:Body>" +
                    "<dsf:FieldExtraction>" +
                    "<dsf:inImage>" +
                    "</dsf:inImage>" +
                    "</dsf:FieldExtraction>" +
                    "</soapenv:Body>" +
                    "</soapenv:Envelope>";

                    var dsfUrl = "http://hpldsf-tst.asiapacific.cpqcorp.net:8090/DSFServiceSite/DSFService.svc/basic";
                    request = new XMLHttpRequest();
                        // We're going to be POSTing to this URL and want a synchronous response
                    request.open("POST", dsfUrl, true);
                    request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml;charset=UTF-8");
                    request.setRequestHeader("Content-length", xmlp.length);
                    request.setRequestHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate");
                    request.timeout = 300000;
                    // This header is a required part of the SOAP protocol
                    request.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", '\"http://DSFService/DSFService/FieldExtraction\"');
                    // Now send an XML-formatted SOAP request to the server
                    request.send(xmlp);
                    request.onreadystatechange = handlesoap;


}
}

function handlesoap()
{
    alert("Inside handlesoap function");
    if(request.readyState == 4)
    {
        var xmls = request.responseText;
        var xmlDoc = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(xmls, "text/xml");
        var doc = xmlDoc.documentElement;
        var nvalue = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('FieldExtractionResponse')[0];
        alert("nvalu ="+nvalue);
        if ((nvalue !== null) && (nvalue !== undefined)) 
        {

            ////var docidval = nodes.getAttribute("id");
            ///Mojo.Log.info("docidval:" + docidval);
            dsfxml = xmls; //nodes.nodeValue;
            var pattern = /\cM/;

                                // Break the string into pieces separated by the pattern above and
                                // and store the pieces in an array called nameList
                                var nameList = [];
                                nameList = dsfxml.split(pattern);
                                var clean = '';
                                for (i = 0; i < nameList.length; i++) {

                                    clean = clean + nameList[i].replace(pattern, "").trim();
                                }
        }
        else
        {
            alert("nvalue is eitheer null or undefined");
        }
    }
}



    function encode(input) {
    alert("I am in encode function");
    var _keyStr = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";
    var output = "";
    var chr1, chr2, chr3, enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4;
    var i = 0;

    while (i < input.length) {
        chr1 = input.charCodeAt(i++) & 0xff; //alert('chr1 : ' + chr1.toString(16));
        chr2 = input.charCodeAt(i++) & 0xff; //alert('chr2 : ' + chr2.toString(16));
        chr3 = input.charCodeAt(i++) & 0xff; //alert('chr3 : ' + chr3.toString(16));

        enc1 = chr1 >> 2;
        enc2 = ((chr1 & 3) << 4) | (chr2 >> 4);
        enc3 = ((chr2 & 15) << 2) | (chr3 >> 6);
        enc4 = chr3 & 63;

        if (isNaN(chr2)) {
        enc3 = enc4 = 64;
        } else if (isNaN(chr3)) {
        enc4 = 64;
        }

        output = output +
        _keyStr.charAt(enc1) + _keyStr.charAt(enc2) +
        _keyStr.charAt(enc3) + _keyStr.charAt(enc4);

    }

    return output;
}

</script>
</html>
```

The problem is its not converting the image properly to base64 format. Can you please help me know where I am going wrong....

Comment: That's quite a bit of code to dig through.. Have you tried stepping through a debugger at least?

Answer (score 1):

It this browser-based?  If so, you're going about this wrong.  If you need to copy from the local hard drive, the page containing your javascript will not be able to access anything on your hard drive at a byte level.  At best, you can provide an upload link, and post your form to the server using something like a 'multipart/form-data' encoding type.

Here's the catch... If your Web service can't understand a form post as is, you may consider creating a proxy to accept the standard form submission, then pass it along through your (urk) SOAP request.  Note that this would be a server API, not a client-side one.

Flow (if needing a proxy):

1).  User navigates to Web page.

2).  User adds image.

3).  User clicks Submit

4).  File is transferred to proxy

5).  Proxy initiates soap request.

6).  Proxy returns results of SOAP request to client.